# What is the .NET Core equivalent of Windows Services

Tags: .net

I have an existing Windows Service. On startup, it enters a loop where it reads from a queue and responds to messages placed on that queue. The application also needs to:

1. Run automatically after it is deployed
2. Should be able to be gracefully started and stopped manually from operations

My current solution is to implement this as a Windows Service and run on Windows Server. Is there an equivalent of this type of application in .NET Core or is there an equivalent of the SCM in Azure or AWS?

Comment: Some simple research on Azure or AWS should point you towards Functions or Lambda, respectively. Or are you absolutely determined to also be dealing with the mechanics of polling for new messages?

Comment: Yes, I think if I were completely in the AWS ecosystem, that would be correct. It looks like even their queue service SQS hooks into Lambda. Unfortunately, I am tied to a ground-based MQ solution that I need to poll for new messages.

Answer (score 1):

[Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io) An easy way to perform background processing in .NET and .NET Core applications. No Windows Service or separate process required.

Backed by persistent storage, open-source framework that helps you to create, process and manage your background jobs.

Check also this article about [Runing Background Tasks in ASP.NET](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx)